# How to add additional column in pytest-html-reporter

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using **Pytest-HTML-Reporter 0.2.9**, it seems very good to me.
But I need to add a column in the report, and that column shows the link or id of my issue created in Gitlab and I don't know how to do it.
Can anybody help me?

I need to add a column here: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF8h2.png)